# How to get nulls rows from datafarmes which are in list in python?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, for-loop

I have two data frames in a list now I want to get null rows columns which are specified in another list. I tried to get but getting an error. Any suggestion about how to do it?

```
l1 = ['b','c']
df_list = [df1,df2]
df1 = 
   a   b   c_r c_c c_d  d  
0  0   q   1    0   0   3  
1  0 NaN   0    0   0   1  
2  0 Nan   0    1   0   4 
3  0   d   0    0   0   5  
4  0 Nan   0    0   1   6 
df2 = 
   a  c    d  b_q b_d c_d
0  0  r    3  1    0   0
1  0  Nan  1  0    0   0
2  0  c    4  0    0   0
3  0  Nan  5  0    1   0
4  0  d    6  0    0   0
```

My code:

```
test_df=[]
for df in df_list:
  for cn in l1:
       test_df.append(df[df[cn].isnull()])
```

Comment: column `b` does not exist in `df2` and `c` does not exist in `df1`

Comment: I only want to get null rows in df1 for b and nulls for c in df2

Comment: then check if the column name exists or not by `for cn in l1: if en in df.columns.values:`

Comment: Cheers Thanks I got it. added an if condition  if cn in df: test_df.append(df[df[cn].isnull()]) and it worked